# Image is upside down in ax.imshow() but changing the origin keyword doesn't fix the problem

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, imshow

Image inside a matplotlib subplot is inverted. Changing the 'origin' keyword from 'upper' to 'lower' doesn't make any difference. When I plot the image separately it plots fine.

I am trying to visualize an image behind a scatter and contour plot in matplotlib. This visualization is one subplot amongst six different subplots. The problem is that the image appears upside down and I tried changing the 'origin' keyword from 'upper' to 'lower' but strangely that doesn't make any difference in my case. Could anyone give me a clue to why this is happening and how to possibly fix this? Following is the relevant part of the code I use. The image is a 560 X 550 X 3 numpy array.

### Problem Code

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2) 

"plot 1"
Dataframe[scorer][bodyparts2plot[0]].plot.scatter('x', 'y', 
               c = '#a98d19', ax=axes[0,0], xlim = (0,560), ylim = (0,550),
               figsize= (20,20), title = bodyparts2plot[3], alpha = 0.1) 
axes[0,0].imshow(image) # plot image
df = Dataframe[scorer][bodyparts2plot[0]][['x','y']]
sns.kdeplot(df,cmap='jet', n_levels=50,ax=axes[0,0]) # plot contour

"plot 2"
Dataframe[scorer][bodyparts2plot[1]].plot.scatter('x', 'y',
                c = '#006666', ax=axes[0,1], xlim = (0,560), ylim = (0,550),
                figsize= (20,20), title = bodyparts2plot[4], alpha = 0.1) 

axes[0,1].imshow(image) # plot image
df = Dataframe[scorer][bodyparts2plot[1]][['x','y']]
sns.kdeplot(df,cmap='jet', n_levels=50, ax=axes[0,1]) # plot contour
```

Changing the 'origin' keyword in axes.imshow() to either "upper" or "lower" makes no difference

### This works but not what I want

when I do

```
plt.imshow(image)
```

the image shows fine.

This is the current situation:
[image with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P987g.png)

What i want is the image to be upside down. Like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4DwB.png)
but with all the other stuff overlaid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with your initial pandas `df.plot.scatter()` call, or rather the fact that you specify de `ylim=` in there. You are forcing the axis to start at 0 at the bottom, whereas `imshow()` plots with 0 at the top of the image.

Changing to `df.plot.scatter(..., ylim=(550,0), ...)` should fix the problem

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it! I would have upvoted this but i don't have enough reputation for it .

Comment: If your problem is solved, consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left to indicate that the issue is closed